# String won't allow floating point/ decimal number

Tags: c, arrays, loops, floating-point, numbers

I'm learning C and found this code on a tutorial and it works fine, but if I try to make a decimal number (like 5.5), it prints a negative one in the following arrays and loops itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "stdafx.h"


#define ARBEITER 3
#define TAGE     5
#define ARBEITSKALENDER kalender();

    int zeitkonto[ARBEITER][TAGE];

    /* Fehlerausgabe */
    void error(int n) {
        printf("%d (?) Falsche Eingabe!!\n", n);
    }

    ABFRAGE0: {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < TAGE; i++) {
            printf("\n\t[Eingeloggt als: %s ] Tag %d in der Woche\n", vorname, i + 1);
            printf("\t-------------------\n\n");
            for (j = 0; j < ARBEITER; j++) {
                printf("Arbeiter Nr.%d in Std.: ", j + 1);
                scanf("%ld", &zeitkonto[j][i]);
                if (zeitkonto[j][i] > 24) {
                    printf("Ein Tag hat nur 24 Stunden?\n");
                    PCLEAR WHALLOWELT ABSATZ goto ABFRAGE0;
                }
                if (zeitkonto[j][i] > 47) {
                    printf("Wer wünscht sich nicht, man hätte mehr Zeit?");
                    PCLEAR WHALLOWELT ABSATZ goto ABFRAGE0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is a "point number"? What is this code supposed to do? What actually happens?

Comment: Can you please narrow down the code to the one function that you have problem with?

Comment: I mean a number like "5.5" or something. 

It is supposed to read how long they worked per day and count up to day number 5. After that the other functions are able to say what the average worktime per day was, which worker worked for how long on what day and so on .. just some test-funcs.

Comment: Try writing the smallest possible testprogram to reproduce such problems. 5 lines should be sufficient here.

Comment: You can not read a flotting point value when telling the scanner to read in an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want floating point numbers in `zeitkonto`, replace :

```
int zeitkonto[ARBEITER][TAGE];
```

by

```
double zeitkonto[ARBEITER][TAGE];
```

and replace

```
scanf("%ld", &zeitkonto[j][i]);
```

by

```
scanf("%f", &zeitkonto[j][i]);
```

and also replace any

```
printf("...%ld...", zeitkonto[...][...]) ;
```

by

```
printf("...%f...", zeitkonto[...][...]) ;
```

Comment: If I enter "5.5" when zeitkonto is an int, my program thinks the entered Value is higher than 24 ... But so far so good. After all it doesn't print that annoying error. If I turn it to double it gives an error, again. What now?

Comment: If you have `scanf("%ld", &x)` then `x` must be of type `int`. If you have `scanf("%f", &x)` then `x` must be of type `double`.

Comment: Fixed it right now .. Thank you very very much!

Now it works like a charm :)

Comment: Suggest `scanf("%lf" ...`

Answer (score 1):

I'm *guessing* it's the `scanf` in the `kalender` function you have problem with.

If you read [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that the function returns the number of successfully scanned items. In your case, it will return one, zero or `EOF`.

If `scanf` returns one, you successfully read an integer. If it returns `EOF` the user pressed the end-of-file key combination (or there was another error). The case you really have to look out for is when `scanf` returns zero, which will happen if you enter something unexpected, like a *floating point* value. If `scanf` fails (when it returns zero or `EOF`) it will *not* change the value of the variable.

---

The question have been edited, and I see that I was focusing on the wrong `scanf`. However, my answer (including the hints on how to solve the problem) is still valid.

---

If you *do* want to be able to read floating point numbers, you should of course change the format to `"%f"` or `"%lf"`, and you must *also* change the array base type from `int` to `float` or `double`.

Comment: My program tells me I can't do that, because `i` and `j` need to be integers.

Comment: @MarcTorvalds Try the `"%lf"` format, with `double zeitkonto[ARBEITER][TAGE];`. Note the **`double`** type. You should not change the type of the index variables.

Comment: [link](http://pl.vc/3byxa)

Here's a screenshot of what the program gives out. It loops itself, again .. although I shortened the code and pasted it to an own .c-File for it.

Answer (score 0):

`zeitkonto` is an array of integers - whole numbers. You need fractional numbers, in particular floating point. That means using `double` and `%lf` to read them.

Comment: I tried that already - Visual Studio didn't like this that much. It said I need to use them in as integers otherwise it'd be wrong.. It simply says that `i` and `j` have to be integers.

Comment: Well, it's the correct solution for your problem, so the problem must have been with the exact code you had then.